# EXCEL: Macros Disabled Error Msg and Double Pressing ENTER

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

This XLS built with a user defined function (UDF) and some other VBA works and has worked for a couple of  years without issue.  That is until a new image of Win10 was loaded onto my work computer. So I have little control over the computer.  There are 2 issues in the XLS: 1) Recurring 'macros disabled' message and 2)  having to double tap ENTER (or TAB) to leave an edited cell.

**Issue 1 is this "error" message pops up repeatedly:"Because of your security settings macros have been disabled. To run macros, you need to reopen this workbook, And then choose to enable macros." [image: "Because of your security settings macros have been disabled. To run macros, you need to reopen this workbook, And then choose to enable macros."]**

1. When the XLS opens, there is no pop up option to enable macros, so "reopen this workbook" does NOT solve the problem.  It only repeats the problem.
2. When the XLS is opened, "Application add-ins have been disabled.  Enable Content"  is the only pop-up option provided.  Enabling that content does not resolve the issue.  [image: "Application add-ins have been disabled. Enable Content"]
3. Macros are enabled in Excel Options according to what I see and cannot be changed.
   [image: see]

**Experiments and observations with "calculating"**
[image: "calculating"[4]]

A.  Press Calculate - Recalculates workbook - Results in 'macros disabled' msg.
[image: Press Calculate]

B.  Press Calculate Sheet - Recalculates just the active worksheet - Results in NO error msg.

C.  Slow double tap ENTER (or TAB) after editing a cell - No error msg. - Assume only the active worksheet recalculates.

D.  Fast double tap ENTER (or TAB) after editing a cell - Results in 'macros disabled' msg. - Initially this resulted in 2 recalculations.  The first, immediate calculation gave no error msg, then a few seconds later, another automatic recalculation resulted in the 'macros disabled' msg.  Currently it appears to only calculate once now, resulting in the error msg.  I have no guess as to why it calculated 2x then changed just to one, unless it was some of the extraneous VBA I removed from the XLS and PERSONAL workbooks.

This recurring msg gets annoying when trying to enter data.

**All that said, issue 2 - having to press ENTER (or TAB) twice to advance to the next cell after editing a cell.**  If I could resolve this, maybe C and D above are no longer an issue.  My options  are set to advance down when pressing ENTER.
[image: options]

I read somewhere that VBA with a Workbook_Change event could be the culprit, but I've removed any VBA with Workbook_Change and still the issue persists.

Thoughts on either issue? 
As i see it, there are 2 options:
- There is an error in the VBA that needs to identified and corrected
- There is no error in the VBA and I need a VBA or other type of work around

To preempt suggestions to ask my work IT support - No, they are the most useless meatsacks in existence.  I've already engaged them on a different, but macro-related issue on a different computer.  After a month, someone got back to me and thought macros were some sort of program that had to be installed.  And they will never change the GPO for minion like me.

It's very aggravating that these issues have appeared when I changed nothing in the XLS and there was no issues previously.

For reference, the vba used is in this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31033809/create-excel-user-defined-function-udf-that-can-sum-mixed-numbers-and-text

Comment: If IT have changed the security restrictions on your PC there is nothing we can do to help ...

Comment: The issue may not be with a Workbook_Change event but rather a Worksheet_Change event. Do you have any code associated with any individual worksheets in your workbook? You can check by opening the VBA editor (Alt+F11) and then double-clicking on each sheet listed in the Project Explorer pane.

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce the issues in another work machine?

Comment: What do you mean by XLS? Excel? And did its version change? Were there new add-ons added in this version?

Comment: Yep, put a ticket in with your IT group...

Comment: I can't tell for the ones saying put in an IT ticket if that's supposed to be sarcasm or you're serious.

Comment: @Excellll
There are 3 SUB modules in VBA + 1 FUNCTION module.  The user defined FUNCTION can be found as an answer in the link above.  None of the modules have a Worksheet_Change event.

The only Worksheet code there is, is this:
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

This is used in conjunction w/ conditional formatting to highlight the active row.  I use this in most of my spreadsheets at work w/ **no issues**.

Comment: @Ricardo Diaz   I don't have access to another PC at work.  I opened the spreadsheet at home and there were no problems.

Comment: I was hoping that maybe there is a work around to prevent workbook calculations since those seem to produce the error message.  Worksheet only calculations  do not result in the error msg.

Comment: Maybe some macros at the personal workbook macros could be causing these issues?